# PrestaShop cannot see PHP files

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

I've asked this on PrestaShop's forums but they don't like to answer.

But I have a PrestaShop installation for our store and a few of our modules require AJAX/jQuery back to a .php file, but even if the PHP file exists we still get a "404 File Not Found"

It has a minor mod_rewrite on it to enable cleaner URL's e.g:

/group/product_name_number.html

This is the only web domain it's happening on, It's not happening on our other ones which are all on the same VPS.

PrestaShop .htaccess:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: testing.tangopop.com.au
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

I have physically confirmed the files are there and can be access via FTP, If it's any other extension but .php it's fine for example:

```
/file_name/file_name/test.php -> Error: 404
/file_name/file_name/test.html -> Success
/file_name/file_name/test.gif -> Success
```

If you are able to help that will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Kris

Comment: Enable rewrite logging, and find out what's going on ...

Comment: I'm trying to but I get a continous "LogLevel not allowed here"

Comment: Context for that directive is `server config, virtual host, directory`, so you can't set it in .htaccess, you have to do it at an upper level (but that shouldn't be a problem on a VPS.)

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/Jz38ZmxT)[/link] This is the latest Log from there with debug on the directory.

Comment: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module

Comment: @pokeybit - These aren't my modules, these are modules created by PrestaShop developers that they're not facing issues any where else, just on my server. The modules are created by Eway (Australian Credit Card Processing Company) & Another module

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/MimT68AS) - Cpanel captured more information

Comment: Ok, so not a rewrite issue then - `pass through /.../modules/preorderandnotification/cron.php` confirms this, "pass through" is the rewrite engine saying, none of the rules/conditions applied here, so I am going to pass this on to the rest of the request handler chain to be handled normally. -- I think it is much more likely, considering the file name and therefor purpose of that script it lets deduce, that this script deliberately tries to hide itself in "the cloak of invisibility" [...]

Comment: by responding with a 404, when certain conditions are not met. As a "cron", it is likely to perform some heavy tasks - so it has probably some measures build in to prevent it to be called from just anywhere (otherwise I could embed this for example using `<img src="...">` or a self-submitting form on a highly frequented website, and ddos your server easily.) Check with the documentation and/or the code - it might require a certain kind of key or token ...

Comment: I've disabled the module with the CRON but the issue is still coming back with a 404, I've disabled friendly re-writes, but then it comes up with an Internal Server Error even with the .htaccess deleted

Comment: @NoMansLand see this https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/283209-solved-htaccess-generates-error-500/